# gzip compression doesn't work and can't get 304 in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, caching, compression, gzip

I'm working on a compression and caching mechanism in my asp.net mvc 5 app.

I'm sending files with the following cache headers:

```
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1).ToUniversalTime());
            Response.Cache.SetLastModified(System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(serverPath).ToUniversalTime());
            Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
```

IE11, Edge, Firefox, all sends the If-Modified-Since header on F5 refresh, but not Chrome. Why is that and how to workaround it? In Chrome I got 200 status code and file is loaded from cache.

The second problem I have is with enabling gzip compression.
I have a standard action filter for this:

```
public class CompressContentMvcAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            GZipEncodePage();
        }

        private bool IsGZipSupported()
        {
            string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) &&
                    (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || AcceptEncoding.Contains("deflate")))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void GZipEncodePage()
        {
            HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            if (IsGZipSupported())
            {
                string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

                if (AcceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    Response.Filter = //new GZipCompressionService().CreateCompressionStream(Response.Filter);
                        new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(Response.Filter,
                                                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                    Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Encoding");
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Filter =// new DeflateCompressionService().CreateCompressionStream(Response.Filter);
                        new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(Response.Filter,
                                                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
                    Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Encoding");
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                }
            }

            // Allow proxy servers to cache encoded and unencoded versions separately
            Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Content-Encoding");
        }
    }
```

I apply this filter on my action method returning application assets, but it got the Transfer-Encoding: chunked for each file, not gziped.
This filter is copied from my previous project and there it is still working at is expected. Could it be a problem with IIS server? Locally I have a IIS 10 and .NET 4.7, the the older app, where it works is hosted on IIS 8.5 and framework 4.5. Can't think of anything else. I'm googling the second day and can't find any clue.
I'm not interested in compressing in IIS.

[edit]

Header I got from response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/javascript
Expires: Sat, 18 May 2019 08:58:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 May 2018 13:26:02 GMT
Vary: Content-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 08:58:48 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use Fiddler to inspect these kind of challenges.

**The F5/If-Modified-Since issue.**

Chrome just doesn't make a new request if the expires header has been set and its datetime value is still actual. So Chrome is respecting your expected caching behaviour. When navigating over your website via an other browser, you 'll see that also these don't send any requests for these assets. F5 is 'special', it's a forced refresh.

**The chunked/gzip issue**

Clear your browser cache and inspect the first response. Fiddler will show 'Response body is encoded', which means compressed (gzip or deflate).

Whether you see Transfer-Encoding chunked depends on whether the Content-Length header is present. See the difference in the responses below. If you don't want the chunked Transfer-Encoding set the Content-Length header.

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Sat, 25 May 2019 13:14:11 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 May 2018 13:14:11 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Content-Length: 5292

Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Sat, 25 May 2019 13:14:11 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 May 2018 13:14:11 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

Because you are handling the serving of assets via your own code, instead of via the IIS static files module, you have to deal with all response headers yourself.